# "Freezing" whole application programmatically

Tags: c, multithreading, breakpoints, freeze

I am writing a debugger application for C programmes that uses my lib. the debugger gets the app name and run it ( fork ).

I send debugging messages  from the app to my debugger ( each time it enters some funcs in the lib ). I need an ability to freeze the app  on specific events by the debugger ( when the messages buffer is full or when the user decides ).

**I have access to the lib the app uses**

How it can be done? ( even in multithreaded apps )

**I prefer not to use external tools like gdb.**

Comment: All the functionality you describe is provided by `gdb`.

Comment: I know but I cant be depended on gdb. plus gdb uses "hacks" because he dont have access to the app.  I have access to the libs

Comment: If you were doing this on the Windows platform, for example, you would need some help from the Debugging API, [see here for a starting point, and its related articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> I need an ability to freeze the app

[`kill(pid, SIGSTOP);`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill)